# No data retrieved for specific collection Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-animation

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to build a food delivery app.
I managed to load the categories from Firebase using a provider, but the exact same code wont work for my restaurants.
Basically, the list of restaurants retrieved is null. It gives me no errors, just that.

this is Restaurant Model

```
class RestaurantModel{
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const ID = "id";
  static const AVG_PRICE = "avgPrice";
  static const RATING = "rating";
  static const RATES = "rates";
  static const IMAGE = "image";
  static const POPULAR = "popular";

  int _id;
  String _name;
  double _avgPrice;
  double _rating;
  String _image;
  bool _popular;
  int _rates;

  //GETTERS

  int get id => _id;
  String get name => _name;
  double get avgPrice => _avgPrice;
  double get rating => _rating;
  String get image => _image;
  bool get popular => _popular;
  int get rates => _rates;

  RestaurantModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    _id = snapshot.data()[ID];
    _name = snapshot.data()[NAME];
    _avgPrice = snapshot.data()[AVG_PRICE];
    _rating = snapshot.data()[RATING];
    _image = snapshot.data()[IMAGE];
    _popular = snapshot.data()[POPULAR];
    _rates = snapshot.data()[RATES];

  }

}
```

Restaurant services

```
    class RestaurantServices {

  String collection = "restaurants";
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<List<RestaurantModel>> getRestaurants() async => _firestore.collection(collection).get().then((result){
    List<RestaurantModel> restaurants = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot restaurant in result.docs) {
      restaurants.add(RestaurantModel.fromSnapshot(restaurant));
    }

    return restaurants;
  });



}
```

And Restaurant Provider

```
class RestaurantProvider with ChangeNotifier{

  RestaurantServices _restaurantServices = RestaurantServices();
  List<RestaurantModel> restaurants = [];

  RestaurantProvider.initialize(){
    _loadRestaurants();
  }

  _loadRestaurants() async {

    restaurants = await _restaurantServices.getRestaurants();
    notifyListeners();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Future<List> is return only the FutureOr so we only need to wait and get the value from the async function like below

```
 await _restaurantServices.getRestaurants().then((value){
      restaurants = value;
      notifyListeners();
    });
```

I hope it will help you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Nope, same problem, the thing is, I read another collection for Categories before this one, do you think that is the problem?

Comment: Can you place the print(restaurants) before calling the notifyListeners and share the output .it will help me to understand more clear